# EF5 doesn't track Identity oracle field after insert and saveChanges()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g

So, I'm trying to get the Id of the inserted object using entity framework 5 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess but it keeps returning 0 although it inserts correctly in db.

I use an ID column with a sequence and trigger in the Database.

*note: I use database first approach.

Here is the code:

```
var test_trans = new TEST_TRANSACTION101() {
NAME = tran.Name,
TEST_NUMBER =tran.Test_Number
};

_context.TEST_TRANSACTION101.Add(test_trans);

_context.SaveChanges();
int id = test_trans.ID; // here it should retrieve the id from db
```

I used `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)`
and many other solutions I found here nothing seems to work.

It seems that ef doesn't track my entity. Any help?!

Comment: How is `ID` defined in the table? If you're relying on EF to create the identity column, it may not have done that. [From what I'm seeing](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1), Oracle introduced `GENERATED AS IDENTITY` in 12c and you have 11g tagged, so you need a trigger and a sequence.

Comment: Yeah i use a trigger and a sequence and it inserts properly.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of search I've found that Entity Framework misGenerate my data model. So I had to open model designer and make property Id as Identity myself.